# How to configure GeckoView in Kotlin DSL project?

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl, geckoview

I was following the [official mozilla tutorial to setup GeckoView](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView#Get_Started), but I couldn't get it right. The tutorial was using Groovy DSL, so I tried to convert each statement they told me into Kotlin DSL syntax. However, I got this error: "Failed to resolve: org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-nightly:70.0.20190712095934".

This is my `settings.gradle.kts`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            setUrl("https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2/")
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

This is my `build.gradle.kts` module level

```
plugins {
    ...
}

android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...

    // GeckoView
    implementation("org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-nightly:70.0.20190712095934")
}
```

I didn't define the `ext` block, because I'm not sure how the syntax works, instead I just set the version directly to the `implementation`.

Comment: You've added `https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2` as a plugin repository, but you should add a build repository https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:plugin-vs-build-repos